# After uninstall the program data file remain same as before in Vista

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista, uninstallation

I have developed a win form application with .NET 3.5 and C# in Visual Studio 2008. This application using Microsoft Access 2003 file as database. My development machine have Windows XP installed.

When I've completed the development of the application, I've created setup project for this, which is keeping the database in windows Common Application Data folder (in XP: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data, and in Vista: C:\ProgramData).

I've installed the application in Vista and XP machine. Its working as desired except few small bugs. Then I've uninstalled the program and installed it again in XP and Vista machine. And here comes the BIG issue. In XP it s working nicely. But in Vista the program displaying an error which saying some data file path is missing (I am saving some file path in DB field.) After some research I found that this error actually raised for some files which was created after previous install. My question is, i have uninstalled the program successfully, so the database i used is also deleted physically, then how the newly installed application find data from previously installed application?

This is only happening in Vista (don't know about Win 7). Please let me know if anyone solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you create files by your application, how setup will know about them and delete on uninstall? Create custom action.

Comment: Which files creating by my application, I've deleted them on uninstall. But the DB file was creating by the setup project and deleted on uninstall automatically. I confirm the deletion of DB file by checking the file system after uninstall.

Now I am deleting the DB file on uninstall manually. But the problem is also there, if I install the program again, Its finds the data from previous installation.

Comment: @Iftekher: How about a checkbox: `[] delete application data completely`? unfortunately i'm not so familiar with msi to tell you a reason why does this file remain